# Pyspark keeps hanging on dataset while Pandas works very well

Tags: python, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I am following this tutorial:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-develop-a-credit-risk-model-and-scorecard-91335fc01f03

I implemented it successfully in Google Colab. Now, Im trying to convert it into Pyspark. However, Pyspark keeps hanging and keeps causing out of memory issues.
This is my code:

Downloading data from drive:

```
%cd "/content/drive/MyDrive/"

!gdown --id "1xaF743cmUgI5kc76I86AeZDE84SMkMnt"
```

Initializing spark session:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("program2") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled",True)\
    .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","16g").getOrCreate()
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.executor.memory', '10G') \
        .set('spark.driver.memory', '10G')\
        .set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '10G') \
        .set('spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max', '128m')\
        .set('spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb', '128m')
        
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
sc 
# config = SparkConf().setAll([('setMaster', '1') ])

# sc.stop()

# sc = SparkContext(conf=config)
df = spark.read.load("loan_data_2007_2014.csv",format="csv", sep=",", inferSchema="true", header="true")
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

This drops columns that have more than 80% null values

```
null_counts = df.select([F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
# to_drop = [k for k, v in null_counts.items() if v > 0]
# df = df.drop(*to_drop)
count = df.count()
to_drop = []
for k,v in null_counts.items():
  if v > 0.8 * count:
    to_drop.append(k)
df = df.drop(*to_drop)
```

This creates label col

```
df = df.withColumn('good_bad',when(df.loan_status.isin(['Charged Off', 'Default', 'Late (31-120 days)','Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Charged Off']),1).otherwise('0'))
```

This separates categorical and numerical columns

```
# label columns
colLabel = "good_bad"

# categorical columns
colNum = ["member_id","loan_amnt","funded_amnt","funded_amnt_inv","int_rate","installment","annual_inc","dti","delinq_2yrs","inq_last_6mths","mths_since_last_delinq","open_acc","pub_rec","revol_bal","revol_util","total_acc","out_prncp","out_prncp_inv","total_pymnt","total_pymnt_inv","total_rec_prncp","total_rec_int","total_rec_late_fee","recoveries","collection_recovery_fee","last_pymnt_amnt","collections_12_mths_ex_med","mths_since_last_major_derog","policy_code","acc_now_delinq","tot_coll_amt","tot_cur_bal","total_rev_hi_lim"]

#numerical columns

colCat = list(__builtin__.filter(lambda x: x != colLabel and x not in colNum  , df.columns))


colCat
```

This imputes missing values

```
cols = colNum
for col in cols:
  df = df.withColumn(
    col,
    F.col(col).cast(DoubleType())
  )

from pyspark.ml.feature import Imputer
imputer = Imputer().setInputCols(colNum).setOutputCols(colNum).setStrategy("median")
model = imputer.fit(df)
imputeddf = model.transform(df)
```

This normalizes numerical values

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = cols, outputCol="features")

adf = assembler.transform(imputeddf)



scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol=("features"), outputCol=("scaledFeatures"),withStd=True, withMean=True)


scalerModel = scaler.fit(adf)

# Normalize each feature to have unit standard deviation.
sdf = scalerModel.transform(adf)
```

This is to Label encode categorial columns

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

# from pyspark.sql.functions import array_contains, col, explode
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
# colCat.append("id")
l1 = ["id", "issue_d","url","desc","earliest_cr_line","last_pymnt_d","next_pymnt_d"]
colCat = [x for x in colCat if x not in l1]
for c in colCat:
  print(c)
  
  ndf = sdf.withColumn(c+"_num", F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy(sdf[c])))

# indexer = StringIndexer(inputCols = colCat, outputCols=[k+"_num" for k in colCat])
# df = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
# df.select([colCat[0], colCat[0]+"num"]).show(5)
# indexer.fit(df).labels
# idxHousing.select(["ocean_proximity", "ocean_proximity_num"]).show(5)

colCat
```

After this my code stops working. It doesn't even execute df.show(). String Indexer has memory leak issue but writing my own code doesn't work either. 4M isnt a big enough dataset. It is working fine in Pandas then why is it creating an issue in Spark. Although the purpose of spark is to handle large amounts of data

Answer (score 0):

Spark doesn’t work the way Pandas does. so in a nutshell, All you computations are running in a single go(read lazy evaluation in spark). few suggestion I have for you:

1. avoid collect statement at any point of your code. like at null columns identification, you can implement it without collecting. search out for a way I am sure it will be easy.
2. Since you are applying transformation using ML Lib would recommend you to create interim tables after significant interval. Ex. you can create one interim table after cleaning the data, one after normalisation or likewise.
3. repartitioning/coalesce: You need to understand you data partition and how it is being shuffled. just for a case like this, I would recommend you to repartition while writing your interim table. Repartition number you can bring like this : Partition = executor*cores

This will significantly eliminate your problem and will make this pipeline more scalable and robust.

Comment: Please explain point 2 a bit more

Comment: After imputing missing values. you can write your df to a parquet file. something like this:
`df.repartition(300).write.parquet("/tmp/test.parquet")
df = df.read.parquet("/tmp/test.parquet")`

Comment: ?Isnt too many read/write to disk an expensive operation

Comment: Will this partition into 300 splits and write each one to worker node?

Comment: if you are using onprem cluster then Yes it will write to multiple worker node's disk. if cloud then it will write to cloud buckets.

Comment: running it locally google colab